# Is there a complete walk through for a Ruby/Mechanize login, including cookies

Tags: ruby, forms, nokogiri, mechanize

I've got a website im attempting to log into with Ruby / Mechanize and Nokogiri.

I've supplied all of the required information however it seems that I cannot print out the resulting page post login.

A description including:
- cookie usage for mechanize
- usage of hidden fields
- what can be used in the chrome network profile tool to ensure that im passing all the needed parameters.

Comment: Any code you have written? look at this http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html for examples. Beyond this we cant help since there isn't enough info in your question.

Comment: I was hoping for a walkthrough on what requests are pushed out and whats received back.  I could provide code and we could trouble shoot that but what I'm after is a knowledge of what happens on the submission of these forms.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize handles the cookies for you the same way a browser would, so you shouldn't need to worry about them. The same goes for hidden fields. Your code should look something like this:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'some_url'
form = page.forms[0]
form['email'], form['password'] = email, password
logged_in_page = form.submit
```

If you are not getting the response you expect, try comparing the request with the request your browser makes. The easiest way to compare the requests is to proxy both through a debugger such as charles or fiddler.